# Passing a variable in System() c++

Tags: c++, windows

```
if (t.elapsed_millisecs() > 500) {
     system(("powershell(Get - WmiObject - Namespace root / WMI - Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1, " + brightness + string(")")).c_str());
     t = {};
}
```

brightness is just an int that can be set from 1 to 100

I'm trying to change the brightness over a certain amount of time but I'm having problem with system() function. When the program tries to execute the system() function, the cmd outputs " '_' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

My question is how do you pass a variable to the system function correctly?

Comment: std::to_string(brightness) ? right now im pretty sure youre offsetting that char* by the value of brightness (and then concatenating ")" onto that) which is not what you want

Comment: You can't. `system()` takes exactly a single variable, a single parameter, a C character string. Therefore, what you should be asking is how to create a string like that. Do you know how to use `std::ostringstream`, and `std::string`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i tried making a separate string and it didn't work either

Comment: I didn't say simply "string", but I mentioned `std::string` and `std::ostringstream`. This is an explicit reference to a specific set of C++ classes that do this. Furthermore, I don't know what "it didn't work either" means. I can only comment on code that's shown to me.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/269ca073b9c07513
Clang spits out a warning for that code (int plus string does not append) also std::to_string does the trick (yes you could go for stringstream but eh)

Comment: @Borgleader this did the trick, I was including the std:: but i had already put at the top using namespace std, so I just had to take out std::. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are taking liberty with spaces in your example.

This one runs OK:

```
int brightness = 42;
string s = "powershell(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1, ";
s += to_string(brightness);
s += ")";
cout << s;
system(s.c_str());
```

It doesn't change the brightness though, but I don't know `WMI`...

I can run this in PowerShell console:

```
$myMonitor = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\wmi -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods
$myMonitor.wmisetbrightness(3,50)
```

Same result - no errors, no effect.

**UPDATE:**

It works! (I was testing over Remote Desktop at first)